# MySQL + PHP + Query multiple columns in a table based on multiple inputs, not all inputs required

Tags: php, mysql

I want to be able to query a table in my database using multiple form inputs which relate to several columns in the table. The problem I am running into is that not all of the form inputs are required.

A little detail...

I have a table called users. This table has many columns, but the ones I am querying are first_name, last_name, location, status (0 or 1).

I have three inputs on the search form. Name (text), Location (select) and Status (select). The user does not have to enter an input for all of the inputs, only one is required.

The main problem I have is writing the query based on the inputs. I can get it to work with multiple else/if statements, for example...

```
if($_POST['name'] && !$_POST['location'] && !$_POST['status']){
$query = '[QUERY THAT MATCHES NAME]';
} else if($_POST['name'] && $_POST['location'] && !$_POST['status']){
$query = '[QUERY THAT MATCHES NAME AND LOCATION]';
} else if($_POST['name'] && $_POST['location'] && $_POST['status']){
$query = '[QUERY THAT MATCHES NAME AND LOCATION AND STATUS]';
} else if {
etc...
}
```

But, this gets really messy, really quickly as I would need to have 9 or so "else if" statements to cover all of the possible scenarios.

My question is, is there a cleaner way to handle this in a single query, or at least with out all of these "else if" statements?

Comment: How about `OR`?

Comment: select * from users where first_name like ? or last_name like ? Etc.  Bind a wildcard (%) to the end of each of the values. You should be able to get all the logic in one sql statement.

Comment: If you want more help, show some of your sql. I’m not sure what your 9 permutations are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something along the lines of:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE';
$flag = 0;
if ($_POST['name']) {
    $query .= ' NAME = "' . $_POST['name'] . '"';
    $flag = 1;
}
if ($_POST['location']) {
    if ($flag) { $query .= " AND "; }
    $query .= ' LOCATION = "' . $_POST['location'] . '"';
    $flag = 1;
}
if ($_POST['status']) {
    if ($flag) { $query .= " AND "; }
    $query .= ' STATUS = "' . $_POST['status'] . '"';
}
```

Although, I'm not sure how much better it will make your code look.

Also this is assuming that you will have at least one value passed through your post request.

Comment: You should rewrite your answer to use prepared statements, or it will be voted down.